# Extracting structure failed

Tags: scala, sbt

I have failed in sbt file

this is the file:

```
name := "TwitterPopularTags"
    
version := "1.0"
    
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
val sparkVersion = "1.5.2"
    
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % sparkVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.3" 
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j" % "3.0.3"
    
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Twitter4J Repository" at "http://twitter4j.org/maven2/",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
)

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "custom_lib"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
[error] insecure HTTP request is unsupported 'twitter4j.org/maven2'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("Twitter4J Repository" at "twitter4j.org/maven2/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true), or by using allowInsecureProtocol in repositories file
[error] insecure HTTP request is unsupported 'twitter4j.org/maven2'; switch to HTTPS or opt-in as ("Twitter4J Repository" at "twitter4j.org/maven2/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true), or by using allowInsecureProtocol in repositories file
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ivyConfiguration' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last csrConfiguration' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (ivyConfiguration) insecure protocol is unsupported [error] (csrConfiguration) insecure protocol is unsupported [error] (ssExtractDependencies) insecure protocol is unsupported
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The reason to this warning is the fact that you are using `http` and not `https`. From `sbt` 1.4.0 [release notes](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.4.0):

> HTTP resolvers require explicit opt-in using .withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)

[This](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/5593) is the PR that added it.

In order to resolve it you need to update the `Twitter4J Repository` resolver to be https. It should be:

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream
```

As mentioned in its [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream/3.0.3) page.